# How to divide two values in same column based off separate date column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 columns (Date and All Customer Count) and would like to make a third (All Customer Growth).

In order to create the third column, I have to divide two values in the same column, seen below. I'm unsure how to divide two values in the same column (all customer count) based on the date column? So that YoY I can see 55%, 57.14% and 6.35%? Been trying to figure this out for hours! Thank you!

[image: Image attached with details]

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()` and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (( cnt * 1.0 / lag(cnt, 12) over (order by date)) - 1)
from t;
```